# Picker with many text fields

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, uipickerview, uipicker

I'm using picker with many text fields, and I want to show "selected item in text field" in the picker automatically.
I tried to use selectRow, but it doesn't work. What should I do? Or where is the right place to put this piece of code?

Note that it works with one field, but when I use it with the other field, it doesn't work.

```
if(genderTxt.isEditing == YES){
    [picker selectRow:[genderTxt.text intValue]-1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

}
if( relationshipTxt.isEditing == YES){
    [picker selectRow:[relationshipTxt.text intValue]-1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: just to be sure, you want "the text field should have text thats currently selected in the picker"? right?

Comment: No, I want the picker shows the selected item in text field
say that text filed contains "Item 5", I want once I clicked on that text, the picker select on "Items 5".
hope you get it!

Comment: You have component 0 in both of your if statements-- is that what you want? Shouldn't that second if statement use inComponent:1?